# Windows 10: Do I have the right retail to get windows?

Tags: windows-10

I have a question about windows 10, I did a method to check which retail I have of windows, (windows 8.1) But I dont get it, can I not get Windows 10?

Name:Windows(R), Enterprise edition
Description: Windows (R) Operating System, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
Partial Product Key: MKKG7
License Status: Licensed
Volume activation expiration: 258276 minute(s) (180 day(s))
Configured Activation Type: KMS

Comment: What leads you to believe you cannot get Windows 10?

Comment: I saw someone say that VOLUME retails cant get windows 10, I have 1 of the updates, KB2976978, Can I still get it? I haven't got WIN10 Icon even after running a script, and rebooting, I tried everything I really could and I guess this is the reason why??

Comment: It will not be the free version as the answers mention because you have Windows Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

You can get windows but you will have to wait till the licenses for Windows Enterprise and Professional are available. Unfortunately you will probably  have to pay a fee or get it from the person you got the Enterprise license from.

This is directly from Microsoft's upgrade page:

> Yes, free! This upgrade offer is for a full version of Windows 10, not a trial. 3GB download required; internet access fees may apply. To take advantage of this free offer, you must upgrade to Windows 10 within one year of availability. Once you upgrade, you have Windows 10 for free on that device.
>
> Windows 10 Upgrade Offer is valid for qualified Windows 7 and Windows
> 8.1 devices, including devices you already own. Some hardware/software requirements apply and feature availability may vary by device and
> market. The availability of Windows 10 upgrade for Windows Phone 8.1
> devices may vary by OEM, mobile operator or carrier. Devices must be
> connected to the internet and have Windows Update enabled. Windows 7
> SP1 and Windows 8.1 Update required. ***Some editions are excluded:
> Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 8/8.1 Enterprise, and Windows RT/RT 8.1.***
> Active Software Assurance customers in volume licensing have the
> benefit to upgrade to Windows 10 enterprise offerings outside of this
> offer. To check for compatibility and other important installation
> information, visit your device manufacturer’s website and the Windows
> 10 Specifications page. Windows 10 is automatically updated.
> Additional requirements may apply over time for updates.
>
> The availability of Windows 10 upgrade for Windows Phone 8.1 devices may vary by OEM, mobile operator or carrier.

Hope this helps.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade

Comment: Thanks for the really quick answer, when do you think Windows 10 for Enterprise is going to be out? Hopefully less than one year? :)

Comment: @Adam From what my sources tell me that the Enterprise ones should be getting to license holders on August 1st.

Comment: Windows 10 is already available via MSDN and the Microsoft Partner Network. My company already had the new MAK on July 29th.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the upgrade, if that’s what you mean. Volume-activated Enterprise Edition installations cannot be upgraded and do not get the free upgrade targeted at end-users.

As per [FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-faq), “What edition of Windows will I get as part of this free upgrade?”:

> Some editions are excluded: Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 8/8.1 Enterprise, and Windows RT/RT 8.1. Active Software Assurance customers in volume licensing have the benefit to upgrade to Windows 10 enterprise offerings outside of this offer.

Further down, “Can Enterprise customers get the free Windows 10 upgrade?”

> Enterprise customers with active Software Assurance subscription in volume licensing have the benefit to upgrade to Windows 10 enterprise offerings outside of this offer.